# Python Pandas: Distribute column of strings equally

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas column of 300000 strings. It consists of 19 unique strings. Now I want to select only lets say 5000 elements of that column but every string should occur equally. Of course that is limited by the minimum/maximum occurence of the strings in that column.

I thought maybe I could use pandas.facotrize, but I really dont know how to mask the column. Is there a numpy/pandas function which iam not aware of?

If I factorize the strings, it is the same like:

```
strings=np.random.randint(19, size=300000)
```

Now I have somehow to mask that array so that every number occur equally and the number of "Trues" is 5000. The perfect mode would be If I also could give the factor in which one of the strings occur to the others, but this is only for addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])

n = 300_000
strings = np.random.choice([*'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS'], size=n)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Col=strings))
```

---

#### `pandas.DataFrame.sample`

Figure out the actual number you need then sample that from each group

```
g = df.groupby('Col')
mx = g.size().max()
nm = g.ngroups
k = min(5000 // nm, mx)

pd.concat([d.sample(k) for _, d in g])
```